# Is it better to avoid sunscreen if I know i'm not going to get burned?

Tags: skin

If I'm going out in the shade/sun for an hour, is it better to not wear any protection? Related, is the sun in small amounts / small intensities good for the skin?

In other words, is a little exposure a good thing that can quickly become a bad thing or should I minimize any and all exposure.

A directly related question, should I ever wear spf 15 or should I just put the max spf on everywhere I go?

edit: My current thoughts (very unscientific) are that wearing SPF 15 for most places provides a good balance between burning too fast and getting natural exposure to the sun.

Maybe the healthiest solution is to use the rub in tanner once per week and use SPF 70 for outings?

Comment: Hi @RunHard, and welcome to the site. Your question about suncreen and skin is considered off-topic according to our [faq]. Please have a look at it to see what is on-topic and off-topic.

Comment: @MattChan if the question were to be rewritten to focus specifically on using sunscreen when running, would it then be on-topic?

Comment: @Moses It depends on how it's written. I can't say whether it's on-topic or not without seeing the rewritten question. Simply adding "... when exercising?" doesn't necessarily make the question on-topic.